# Magento 1.9 .2.4 - 404 All Product Pages - 405 On Duplicate Product and Customer Login

Tags: magento-1.9, product, error, login, http-error-404

Our Magento 1 installation developed the following issues May 30 after 4:00 PM PST:

All Product Pages - 404 across both .ca and .us store views. 
405 error note on duplicating a product in admin panel 
405 errors on customer login to account.

We tried full restore from Siteground Cloud May 28, 29, 30 with no change. All errors remain. We tried restore stock htaccess and turn off URL rewrites. No change.

Reindexed, Flush all caches, disable supercasher. We tried links with index.php/ manually added. All with no luck.

When the restores were applied they were full DB and files but the problem follows. The problem did not exist May 30th before end of work. Now it cant be pinpointed.

Any help would be appreciated. Site tested clean from virus.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not just disable in admin / cpanel / system advanced but completely remove the Siteground Supercacher application from Magento all together. This fixed all errors immediately.

I hope that helps someone.